# label unclear text when change its text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

unfortunately I can't handle the change of txt when the button is clicked, I try to write a txt and overtime that I click the button, this txt value should change and allotting seems right, the only problem is that the printed number is not obvious and it seems some part of previous txt remains with it.

```
package berGenerator;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
public class sscce {
 private JFrame frame;
 private final Action action = new SwingAction();
 private static     int i = 555;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sscce window = new sscce();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public sscce() {
    initialize();
}
/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {


    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 550, 401);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);


    JButton Next = new JButton("Next");
    Next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    Next.setAction(action);
    Next.setBounds(167, 290, 198, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Next);



}
private class SwingAction extends AbstractAction {
    public SwingAction() {
        putValue(NAME, "Next Timeslot/scheduler");
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Some short description");
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        i = i+1;
        frame.getContentPane().validate();
        frame.getContentPane().repaint();
        String from = String.valueOf(i);
        System.out.println("sw is: "+from);
        JTextArea TextArea11 = new JTextArea("");
        TextArea11.setText(from);
        TextArea11.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        TextArea11.setBounds(6, 66, 87, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(TextArea11);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is or what you expectations are (what you're trying to achieve), but, you should avoid using `null` layouts and I don't know why you're creating a new instance of `JTextArea` each time (you're not removing the old instance to start with), but you should just be using `setText("")` to remove the text from a pre-existing instance

Comment: I'd also ecourage you to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: This code is runnable and if you run it, you can see that the showed number are not clear (after the first click). Where should I create in your opinion my JTextArea so I could access it while Action happened?

Comment: Tnx, I am looking on it, and you are right by the way

Comment: Why are you still using validate() and repaint()?? You were specifically told in your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610636/java-jbutton-txt-is-not-clear) that you don't need those methods and all you need is the setText() method.  If you are going to repeat the question then delete your old question so people don't waste time responding when the new discussion is in this posting.

Comment: When I don't use them, it cause some abnormality in this field

Comment: Also, variable names should not start with an upper case character. Why are your variables correct in your last posting but not this posting? No wonder you have problems you don't have any consistency in your code.

Comment: `it cause some abnormality in this field` - even with the code you have a problem or you wouldn't be asking the question, so why did you ignore the advice that specifically told you what to do? You were asked to post your SSCCE that only showed you using setText()!

Comment: firstly I delete that post, thank you for your advise, It really did not reach on mind before

Comment: Which variable you are speaking about?

Comment: `Where should I create in your opinion my JTextArea so I could access it while Action happened?` - take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). The demo code will show you how to better structure your code so the Action can access the text area. Basically all the variables and Action are defined in the same class.

Comment: after that you told me to send you SSCCE, I ask you where I should put my SSCCE code, (because I really don't know) and you did not reply me

Comment: Thanks for your time, I will read it, even if I still don't know where should I put the SSCCE generally

Comment: A SSCCE should be posted with your question so we can see the code you are executing.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify.

Layout managers are fundamental to the Swing API, you should make the time to learn how to use them, they will solve more problems than you think they create.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

You're creating multiple instances of `JTextArea` and adding to the frame, but you're not removing any, you're running into a potential z-ordering problem at best and a major resource management issue at worst.

Instead, simply create a single instance of `JTextArea`, add it to the frame (just like you did your button) and simply update it when the `Action` is triggered, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import static javax.swing.Action.NAME;
import static javax.swing.Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;
    private final Action action = new SwingAction();
    private static int i = 555;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test window = new Test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        textArea.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));

        JButton next = new JButton("Next");
        next.setAction(action);
        frame.getContentPane().add(next, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    private class SwingAction extends AbstractAction {

        public SwingAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "Next Timeslot/scheduler");
            putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Some short description");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            i = i + 1;
            String from = String.valueOf(i);
            System.out.println("sw is: " + from);
            textArea.setText(from);
            textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
}
```